# how create own custom notification bar with pull left

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I want to create my own notification bar when user pull left from right side of his/her device. is it possible or not?
thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But SO is not a code request site, so you probably will not get any responses to a question like this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @karaokyo thanks for your response. can you show me some tutorial or sample projects on other sites to help me?

Comment: You could probably take a look at a [chatheads tutorial](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics).